# Axis2 ADB mapping of Java keywords

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate Axis2 client stubs and bean mappings using ADB for the following WSDL: https://secure.dnb.com.au/CCBB2BService/CreditCheck.asmx?wsdl.

Unfortunately one of the elements in the WSDL is called **Class** and that will result in JAva compiler errors. Is there a way to overcome this problem (using the ADB binding)?

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfClassComponent">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Class" type="tns:ClassComponent"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

This is the command-line I have used:

```
$AXIS2_HOME/bin/wsdl2java.sh -uri https://secure.dnb.com.au/CCBB2BService/CreditCheck.asmx?wsdl --noBuildXML -d adb -s -u -uw -o .
```

Comment: I'd recommend complaining to the people who published this web service.  Also, you could look into using a different framework, e.g. Axis 1 or something else.  Changing to binding will only succeed if it also changes the name back to `Class` before generating the XML output.